# Grok kibana multiline filter

Tags: regex, logstash, multiline, logstash-grok

I am trying to get a full json from a log. for that I am using the following regex:

```
(?m)(?<=content)(.*)(?=,)
```

And when testing on the grok debugger included with kibana I get what I want:

[image]

Now the problem is that when running the application, I get the message I configured for the case when the grok filter doesn't match anything:

[image]

This is the grok filter I'm using:

```
grok {
        tag_on_failure => ["cant parse full response"]
        pattern_definitions => {"full_response" => "(?m)(?<=content)(.*)(?=,)"}
        match => { "message" => "%{full_response:full}" }
      }
```

I asked the guys on discuss.elastic.com but haven't gotten any answer.

Do I have to put these grok filter first? The questions on this site seem to indicate that adding (?m) should be enough.

Comment: `(?m)` would help if the text the regex receives contains newlines.

Comment: Can you add you full pipeline code and also a sample JSON.  Why not use something like `logstash-filter-json` or `logstash-filter-json_encode`